# Why prepend does trigger once in a loop?

Tags: javascript, menu, overflow, appendchild, prepend

I'm not very good at Javascript, I am trying to make an auto collapsing on overflow menu using Vanilla Js. 
I'm happy with what I've managed to do so far. But I have a problem with ```appendChild``` / ```prepend```, they are triggered only once in my loop. When I refresh the page every overflowed link has gone under the more menu, but As I resize (decrease) the window,overflowed links still goes under the more menu, but the more menu itself isn't updating.

```
function collapseMenu() {
let menu = document.querySelector(".menu");
let menuChildren = menu.querySelectorAll('li');
let i = menuChildren.length - 1;

let other = document.createElement("li");
other.setAttribute("onclick", "submenu(this)");
other.id = 'other';
other.innerHTML = 'More';

let submenu = document.createElement("ul");
submenu.classList.add('submenu', 'hidden');
other.appendChild(submenu);

if (menu.offsetWidth >= window.innerWidth) {
    let drop;
    if (!menu.contains(document.getElementById('other'))) {
        menu.appendChild(other);
    }
    while (menu.offsetWidth >= window.innerWidth) {
        drop = menu.removeChild(menuChildren[i]);
        submenu.prepend(drop);
        i--;
    }

} else {
    //On increase window
}

}

collapseMenu();
window.addEventListener('resize', collapseMenu);
```

Please help, thanks

Comment: I'm not seeing any reference to `prepend` in your code here.

Comment: Oh sorry, I replaced it with appendChild at the last moment, like before copying the code and paste it there. I fixed that

Comment: What are `menu.offsetWidth` and `window.innerWidth` when it does run?

Comment: the logic behind it is to execute the function if the width of the menu ```menu.offsetWidth``` is greater than that of the window ```window.innerwitdth```. The menu is a ul list of 16 children. I stylized the ul list with a flex display and a max-content width so it can overflow. Thus, every time it overflows the function is triggered.

Comment: I meant the values. Do those values change while the `while` loop is running?